# select() in socket programming c++ always giving time error

Tags: c++, sockets, select

I have this socket program which has both parts of send and recieve but when  i use select it always returns "Time error " . Here is code

```
void server::run(){
int RetVal;
    struct timeval *tp=new timeval;
    tp->tv_sec=300;
    tp->tv_usec=500000;
    fd_set readfds;
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(sock,&readfds);
    FD_SET(sock1,&readfds);
    cout<<"run() is working fine";
    if((RetVal=select(1,&readfds,NULL,NULL,tp))==SOCKET_ERROR)  //check for incoming packets.
                {
                    cout<< "Timer error!";
                    Sleep(50);
    }
    else if(RetVal>0)   //There are incoming packets.
            {
           if(FD_ISSET(sock1, &readfds))    //incoming packet from peer host 1
         {
           send();
          }
            else if(FD_ISSET(sock, &readfds))   //incoming packet from peer host 1
           {
              send1();
          }
         else{
            cout<<"no port is open to communicate";
         }
}
}

server::server(){
WSADATA wsadata;
try{
    if (WSAStartup(0x0202,&wsadata)!=0)
        throw"Starting WSAStartup() error\n";

    //Display name of local host
    if(gethostname(servername,HOSTNAME_LENGTH)!=0) //get the hostname
        throw"Get the host name error,exit";
}
catch(char *str){
    cerr<<str<<":"<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;
}

    printf("Server: %s waiting to be contacted for time/size request...\n",servername);
}

server::~server(){
    WSACleanup();
}

void server::send(){

try{
        if ((sock= socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            cout<< "SERVER: socket unable to initialize\n";
        }
        servers.sin_family = AF_INET;
        servers.sin_port = htons(port);
        servers.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

        if (bind(sock, (sockaddr*)&servers, sizeof(servers)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            cout<<"SERVER: Cant Bind the Socket";
            closesocket(sock);
        }

       if (listen(sock, MAXPENDING) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        //if((value=listen(sock, MAXPENDING))==SOCKET_ERROR)
       {
            cout<<"SERVER: listening socket not open";
            closesocket(sock);
       }


       if ((clientSock= accept(sock, 0, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
       {
           throw"SERVER: connection not accepted";
       }


       if ((nBytes= send(clientSock, "Hello", 20, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
       {
           throw"SERVER: data sending failed ";
       }
    }
    catch(char *str){
    cerr<<str<<":"<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;
    }

       closesocket(clientSock);
       closesocket(sock);
       }

void server::send1(){
try{
        if ((sock1= socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            throw "SERVER: socket unable to initialize\n";
        }
        servers.sin_family = AF_INET;
        servers.sin_port = htons(port);
        servers.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

        if (bind(sock1, (sockaddr*)&servers, sizeof(servers)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            throw"SERVER: Cant Bind the Socket";
            closesocket(sock1);
        }

       if (listen(sock1, MAXPENDING) == SOCKET_ERROR)
       {
            throw "SERVER: listening socket not open";
            closesocket(sock1);
       }

       cout << "SERVER: Ready to run now...";

       if ((clientSock= accept(sock1, 0, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
       {
           throw"SERVER: connection not accepted";
       }


       if ((nBytes= send(clientSock, "Hello", 20, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
       {
           throw"SERVER: data sending failed ";
       }

    }
    catch(char *str){
    cerr<<str<<":"<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;
    }

       closesocket(clientSock);
       closesocket(sock1);


}
```

I have tried so many things but my select() is always returning same thing.
My program is working fine without run() and select() if i call send and recv() directly its working fine. but select() is not working i guess.

Comment: You have a memory leak, each loop you allocate a new `timeval` structure but you never free it.

Comment: The first argument of `select` is wrong. Make it `sock1+1`. Also, allocating `struct timeval` on the heap is utterly pointless. Use a local variable and pass its address to `select`.

Comment: What is the value of `errno`?

Comment: This is the Windows socket library, so `errno` will not be set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `select` function returns `SOCKET_ERROR` (or actually `-1`) on *error* and `0` on timeout. When you get an error (and not a timeout), you should use `WSAGetLastError` to get the actual error, and look it up in e.g. [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You should also set the first argument to the highest socket number + 1 to be portable.

---

You have a larger problem though, it seems you do not create the actual sockets until *after* you call `select`. This means that the sockets used in the `select` call will be invalid, and that's the reason you get your error.

Normally one creates the sockets first, binds them to the local address and mark them as listening sockets. *Then* you do `select` on the sockets, and when readable they have incoming connections that can be accepted.

I think you need to rethink your design.

---

You should also think about what will happen *after* you have accepted a connection. Right now you just accept a connection, send some text and then close it again. But if you want to continue communicating on the accepted sockets, and possibly have more than a single connection, you have much more work to do.

You also try to create two sockets bound to the same local address, and that will not work. Remember that a passive listening socket can actually accept any number of incoming connections, not just a single one.

To check which which sockets you can receive data on, you use e.g. `select`, with a read-set containing all accepted connections, plus your listening socket.

Comment: its giving me error 
WSAENOTSOCK
10038

 

Socket operation on nonsocket.

    An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket. Either the socket handle parameter did not reference a valid socket, or for select, a member of an fd_set was not valid.
 but i have both my other sockets working.

Comment: @networks Just updated my answer with why `select` will not work.